# Pyside6 mouse coordinate relative to image

Tags: python-3.x, coordinates, mouseevent, pyside6

Let suppose I have an image correctly rendered in a QLabel

As I want to get mouse position relative to the image I'm subclassing QLabel and reimplant mouseMoveEvent(self,event) and then build the source_image from this class.Rendering is Ok, but how do I get the event.x() from the parent class ?

I know I have to connect the instance to the ImLabel signals but i'm stuck with implementation.

```
class ImLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    on_mouse_move = Signal()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        print(event.x(), event.y())
        super(ImLabel, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)
```

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.source_image = ImLabel()
        self.source_image.on_mouse_move.connect(self.mouseMoveEvent)
        ...
        self.cursor = QLabel("cursor : ")
        ...
    def mouseMoveEvent(self,event):
        self.cursor.setText('Mouse coords: ( %d : %d )' % (event.x(), event.y()))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "how do I get the event.x() from the parent class"? Also: 1. you're never emitting the `on_mouse_move` signal; 2. overriding `mouseMoveEvent()` (without calling the base implementation) will always result in accepting the event, so no parent widget will ever receive the mouse move event, ***unless*** it was caused by a mouse press on *that* parent.

Comment: @Alexander, relative to the top left corner of the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnally this is the way I made it :

```
class ImLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        super(ImLabel, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)
        self.x,self.y = event.x(),event.y()
```

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    ...

    def mouseMoveEvent(self,event):
        self.cursor.setText('Mouse coords: ( %d : %d )' % (self.source_image.x,self.source_image.y))
```